# Import/Export Data from SQL (Azure Virtual Machine) to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Our current web application uses Azure SQL Database. We need to create a scheduled process for importing/exporting data from a  **SQL database in Azure Virtual Machine** to **Azure SQl database**. And also provide ability to trigger manually.

Currently we have manual scripts with Linked server which needs to be run on both servers.

What are the best options available for clean import/Export data automation (scheduled or manual)? for e.g. Secure Connection between servers, Tools or Applications (other than SSIS)

Could someone please provide guidance.

Thank you,
Vamshi

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql) tool to sync data between an Azure SQL Server VM and an Azure SQL database. The sync can be done manually or scheduled with a frequency of days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Of course, you can also use SSIS for that purpose. But you may see intermittent connection failures that can substantially impact data loads.

You can use Azure Data Factory to [connect](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-connect-adf-to-sql-server-on-azure-vm-using-private/ba-p/3249139) to Azure SQL VM and [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database?tabs=data-factory) and using the copy data tool export/import data from one to the other, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, will try those options.

Comment: @AlbertoMorillo, this is my scenario: a customer does lift-and-shift and everything works fine but the costs of Azure Virtual Machines is high. 
they now would like to move to Azure SQL Database. Can we use to SQL Data Sync to move the database form Azure Virtual Machines to Azure SQL Database with nearly zero downtime?

Comment: Azure SQL Database Migration service does not support online migrations to Azure SQL, so maybe one of the options you have available is using Azure Data Sync that allows to set a sync frequency of seconds and in a one-way direction, and you can set a test scenario. Make sure you tested the compatibility of the SQL Server databases against Azure SQL prior to start the test. Your organization may consider also moving to Azure Managed Instance instead that allows online migrations. And a third option is using Transactional Replication to migrate with minimal downtime.